# how to prevent starts fresh from root activity instead of resuming background state

Tags: android, android-activity

I have app a that starts app b (a-->b),  the user can start app b (b) directly or to start a that start b (a-->b). 
I just want  when user start app a ,  and app b already started by user directly  then it will bring to front the activity of app b.

To the point, if ,y  entering point to the app is deferent, how can i get the current activity if the app already running and not the root one.
If you can post a code or advice.

Comment: Your question is unclear and difficult to follow. You should consider taking the time to rewrite it and focus on being detailed and precise.

Answer (score 1):

When you start activity b, start it with intent flag  FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT